# get_posts - require all categories

Tags: categories

From the `get_posts` docs I see it takes categories as a parameter.

However, is this an `AND` or an `OR`?

i.e. if you specify 2 categories do posts have to be in both to be returned?

If not, how do you specify an `AND` relation? I only want posts that match ALL categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display posts that have "all" of these categories:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=staff+news' );
```

See [this on category parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters).

Answer (score 0):

`get_posts()` passes the data to `WP_Query` as the `cat` argument [as you can see in the source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1863):

```
1863            if ( ! empty($r['category']) )
1864                    $r['cat'] = $r['category'];
```

There is also a note in the source that is relevant:

```
1835     *     @type int|string $category         Category ID or comma-separated list of IDs (this or any children).
1836     *                                        Is an alias of $cat in WP_Query. Default 0.
```

[That is going to match up to this usage](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters):

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=2,6,17,38' );
```

If you run that query you will see that it is an `OR` relationship:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=2,6,17,38' );
var_dump($query->request);
```

More specifically it uses MySQL's `IN()` syntax.

You can push anything through `get_posts()` that will work with `WP_Query` so this should work:

```
$query = get_posts( 'category_name=staff+news' );
```

Or this:

```
$query = get_posts( array('category_name' => 'staff+news' );
```

However, it is cleaner and neater to skip the `get_posts()` function altogether and use `WP_Query` directly. `get_posts()` is really just a thin wrapper anyway and strikes me as code bloat. A taxonomy query will give you all the control you need:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( 2,6,17,38 ),
            'operator' => 'AND'
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: *There is no way to push any other relationship through get_posts()*. Not true :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen : I need to stop posting in the middle of the night :)